# Update data from comboBox using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, updates

I need your help..

In my web site, I let the employee to chose the department name that he wants from comboBox using this code

```
$dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
    $from= "SELECT d.dept_id, d.name FROM department d LEFT JOIN employee e ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id' ";
    $result_form = mysql_query($from);
    //$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_form); // get 1st result row

    $dept_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_form);
$dept_name = $dept_from['name'];
    //$row=mysql_fetch_array($result_form);
    //echo    $row1['name'];

    $date1=date("Y/m/d");
    $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
$query = "INSERT INTO request (`date`, `description`, `from`, `emp_id`, `to`)

    VALUES

('$date1','$_POST[description]','$dept_name','$emp_id','$_POST[to]')";
```

it works correctly

Then the administrator choose the request by employee ID from comboBox when he press the accept button the data should updated

and this is its code

```
if(array_key_exists('accept', $_POST)) { 
   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("employee_transfare", $conn);  
  $emp_id=$_POST['emp_id'];
  $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
   $query="UPDATE employee SET dept_id='$dept_id' WHERE emp_id= $emp_id ";

  $n=mysql_query($query, $conn);

  if($n==0)
    echo "<h2>details already updated </h2>";
  else
    echo "<h2>details successfully updated</h2>";       
  mysql_close($conn);   
  }
else {
```

It always gives details already updated ...

How I can do it?

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: `$dept_id =$_POST['dept_id'];`
`$dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];` Why 2 times to different values?

Comment: our course is using php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

That comparison with 0 seems a bit imprecise.  The following is from the documentation on `mysql_query`:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Instead of `if ($n==0)`, perhaps try `if ($n===FALSE)` or alternately `if (! $n)`.

Comment: is it a correct code?                                                       For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.